# Can I get away with just using aws security groups instead of a full VPN connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, ip, vpn

My question is pretty basic. I know I can set up a server in aws and set a security group that only allows connections for a particular protocol from one ip address. My company has an outward facing IP address and I wanted to know if it's a good idea to essentially allow my "gateway" into my aws infrastructure be determined by that ip address. Obviously a VPN would be more secure but how much more secure. Is it worth setting up a vpn or just saying only this ip from the outside world can connect to this server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If we are talking only about a single server; Just security group is good enough.. though as u mentioned VPN is a cleaner solution.. but more appropriate when u have multiple servers..

Security groups is like IP Tables ; while VPN is like Intranet.

Comment: The correct answer depends on the type of traffic and security levels required. If the traffic is not encrypted and sensitive data is being transferred then you need to use a VPN.

Comment: John Hanley.. I agree

Comment: What if the connection to the server is being made through ssh using a private key? Even if the only protocol that the server will except from the outside is ssh with a key isnt that just as secure as vpn?